# Hydra runtime type checking does not work when config name specified in command line

Tags: python, fb-hydra

The following code snippet works as expected when running the script without any parameters (execution stops because of missing argument in config):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    config_name = "csv_images_test"

    cs = ConfigStore.instance()
    cs.store(name=config_name, node=Config)

    @hydra.main(config_path="/hdd/twapi/configs/", config_name=config_name)
    def main(cfg: Config) -> None:
        print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

    main()
```

How ever, when i specify this config name via command line, it seems that type checking is not happening:

```
python /hdd/twapi/src/config_structure.py --config-name=/hdd/twapi/configs/csv_images_test.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hydra 1.0, the matching between the config and the matched schema is happening automatically when they share the same name.
This is documented [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/schema).

Hydra 1.1 which is still in development changes this behavior in favor of a more flexible usage of the Defaults List to match the schema to the config.
See [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/tutorials/structured_config/schema).

This is possible due to the new Defaults List implemented in Hydra 1.1, which supports Defaults List in arbitrary configs and not just the primary one.

Learn more about it [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/defaults_list).

You can try Hydra 1.1 dev release (latest is [1.1.0dev4](https://pypi.org/project/hydra-core/1.1.0.dev4/)). See the primary readme of Hydra for installation instructions.